# Page Control and table view

Tags: objective-c

I have ios app that contains 7 table view with different data. I fill each table from plist file and I need to have page control and in each page I need one table view. I put the page control , the table which I put it in the first page didnt change I saw it in other pages. How can I determine number of pages and content for each page? I put this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    int page=pageControl.currentPage;

    //pageControlList=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:tabelView,tabelViewq, nil];

    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 424);

    self.tabelView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    NSError *err;
    for (page=0; page<7; page++) {


     switch ([pageControl currentPage]) {
         case 0:{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    //getting the path to document directory for the file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSLog(@"%@",paths);
    NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"News.plist"];

    //checking to see of the file already exist
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        //if doesnt exist get the the file path from bindle
        NSString *correctPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"News.plist"];
        NSLog(@"plist exist");
        //copy the file from bundle to document dir
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:correctPath toPath:path error:&err];
    }


    // read data from plist file
    presedients=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path ];

    Names=[presedients objectForKey:@"Name"];
    url=[presedients objectForKey:@"URL"];
    NSLog(@"%@",presedients);
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
         }
             break;
         case 1:{
             pageControl.currentPage =pageControl.currentPage+1;

             NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
             //getting the path to document directory for the file
             NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

             NSLog(@"%@",paths);
             NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
             NSString *pathq = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Quran.plist"];

             //checking to see of the file already exist
             if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathq])
             {
                 //if doesnt exist get the the file path from bindle
                 NSString *correctPathq = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Quran.plist"];
                 NSLog(@"plist exist");
                 //copy the file from bundle to document dir
                 [fileManager copyItemAtPath:correctPathq toPath:pathq error:&err];
             }


             // read data from plist file
             presedientsq=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:pathq ];

             NamesQ=[presedientsq objectForKey:@"Name"];
             urlq=[presedientsq objectForKey:@"URL"];
             NSLog(@"%@",presedientsq);

         }
             break;
```

but the program see case one (which I put the first table and appear in all the pages). Why? Is my condition is wrong?

Regards

Comment: Do you change the currentPage when you switch pages?

Comment: no i dont change it where i must change it? im new to this field can you help me?

Comment: Check [this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)

Comment: thanks Alexander for your respond but i have a problem i need tabel view to show data stored in plist file how i can call 7 tabels i cant do this!!!??

Comment: Can't you store pointers to each table?

Comment: how i can make this is this for the same view controller